# How to generate missing dates in array from json using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have one date rang json and I need to generate missing dates and store into array but how can I do have no idea.

Here below json:

```
0:{ AvailabilityStatus : 1 
    DateFrom : "2018-08-04 00:00" 
    DateTo   : "2018-08-11 00:00" }
1:{ Status : 1 
    DateFrom : "2018-08-11 00:00" 
    DateTo   : "2018-08-18 00:00" }
 2:{ Status : 1 
     DateFrom : "2018-09-01 00:00" 
     DateTo   : "2018-09-08 00:00" }
 3:{ Status : 1 
     DateFrom : "2018-09-08 00:00" 
     DateTo   : "2018-09-15 00:00" }
```

So above from the json missing date range is **2018-08-19** to **2018-08-31**.
so I need to generate missing dates like this **2018-08-19,2018-08-20,...,2018-08-31** and store into an array.

Answer (score 1):

With the momentJs library (https://momentjs.com/docs/), you could do something like :

```js
var startRange = moment.utc("2018-08-18 00:00").add(1, 'days'); // add one day to the start to not include the start date;
var endRange = moment.utc("2018-09-01 00:00");
var result = [];

while ( startRange.isBefore(endRange, 'day') ) {
  result.push(startRange.toDate());
  startRange.add(1, 'days');
}

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```